# how to set/change toggle button value - laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-8, togglebutton

I have a toggle button to set status from pending to approved, it works fine but I cannot sort the values based on pending or approved.
[image]
Every row value is displayed as PendingApprovedPendingApproved (in console.log). (In database its correctly saved with values 0 and 1). Any solution would be helpful. Thank You

```
  <td>
              <input data-id="{{$college->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="danger"        
                 data-offstyle="info" data-toggle="toggle" 
                data-on="Pending" data-off="Approved" {{$college->status?'checked':''}}>
                                    </td>

<script>
    $('.toggle-class').change(function() {

        var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/changeStatus",
            data: {
                'status': status,
                'id': id
            },

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.success)
          
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

changeStatus

```
 public function changeStatus(Request $request)
    {

        $colleges = College::find($request->id);
        if ($colleges->status == '1') {
            $colleges->status = 0;
        } else {
            $colleges->status = 1;
        }
        $colleges->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Status change successfully.']);
    }
```

filter

```
 <script>
var filters = ["", "", "",""];

function applyNewFilters() {
   
  console.log(filters);
  var rows = $('#myTable').find('tr');
  for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = $(rows[i]); // we're re-applying all filters anyway
    row.show();
  }
  for(var i = 2; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = $(rows[i]);
    for(var f = 0; f < filters.length; f++) {
      //column is going to be equal to f
      var col = $(row.find('td')[f]).text();
      
      console.log(col);
      if(col.indexOf(filters[f]) < 0) {
        row.hide();
      }
    }
  }
}

$('.filter-input').on('change', function() {
  var $modifiedInput = $(this);
  
  console.log($modifiedInput.val());
  var column = $modifiedInput.attr('data-col');
    filters[column] = $modifiedInput.val();
    applyNewFilters();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show example code of your changeStatus function in Laravel, see what it returns

Comment: I have added the code above, it returns 0 or 1.

Comment: there is no `orderBy()` function defined

Comment: @AbdullaNilam even with the function it doesnot work because its taking PendingApprovedPendingApproved value for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Could you replace `$colleges->status == '1'` with `$request->status == '1'` on the changeStatus method first and see what will happen?

Comment: that doesnot update my status and values changes on page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need exactly?
If you need to sort index based on status :

```
College::orderBy('status')->get();
```

Comment: I want to add a textbox below status (search by status) and when the user inputs Pending it should be filtered (all pending at top)

Comment: I think it's better to use check box instead of text box to filter data based on status. Are you agree?

Comment: Any problem? Is your problem solved?

Comment: I have added the filter script above, can I use the same function to filter status?